# Unity game crashes on device home button long press

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash, android-notifications

Edit : The premise of this question was wrong, as it doesn't have anything to do with how long the button is pressed, the app always crashed.
I think I fixed the problem. There was what I would consider a bug in the library github.com/Agasper/unity-android-notifications (it should check if actions[] is null in PopulateActions) and the usual problem with different support library versions. I also use Google PlayGameService which comes with differently versioned support libs. I couldn't delete the old ones, because the PlayServicesResolver would create them again, but I could just deactivate them, which seems to have solved my problem.

Still I'd like to leave the question here in case someone can tell us how to find the error with that error message.

---

In my Unity game I send local notifications in onApplicationPause().

That works. When I press the home button briefly, the app goes in the background, the notifications get send.

But... when I press the home button longer and Androids voice recognition is started the app just crashes with this error :

> 01-31 10:49:29.069: E/AndroidRuntime(1940): Process:
>   com.xx.yy, PID: 1940 01-31 10:49:29.069:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1940): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No
>   direct method (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)V in
>   class Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder; or its super
>   classes (declaration of
>   'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder' appears in
>   /data/app/com.xx.yy-1/base.apk) 01-31
>   10:49:29.073: E/ActivityManager(983): App crashed! Process:
>   com.xx.yy

What does the error mean, what method are we talking about and why does it only crash when I press the home button longer?

Comment: File for a bug report through the Editor.

Comment: How do you send notifications? And what Android version has the issue?

Comment: @Minzkraut I am using https://github.com/Agasper/unity-android-notifications to send notifications. But I think I fixed the problem. There was what I would consider a bug in this library (it should check if actions[] is null in PopulateActions) and the usual problem with different support library versions. I also use Google PlayGameService which comes with differently versioned support libs. I couldn't delete the old ones, because the playservicesresolver would  create them again, but I could just deactivate them, which seems to have solved my problem.